# Has the appearance of the free-jqgrid pager changed?

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I've started exploring free-jqgrid and noticed a change in the way the pager appears.  It now has an extra line at the bottom.  Here's an example:

[image: free-jqgrid pager example]

And here's an example of the way it used to look:

[image]

Why does the free-jqgrid pager have the search and refresh buttons on a separate line at the bottom?  is this the intended appearance?  If so, is there a way to change it so all of the buttons appear on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second grid, which you included in your question, contains no `viewrecords: true` parameter. If you would remove the option, the right part of the pager will be used for other purpose and the navigator buttons will be displayed more compactly.

Wrapping behavior of navigator bar is described in [the old wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Redesign-of-the-structure-of-Navigator-Bar-of-the-pagers). Without wrapping (in old jqGrid) the navigator buttons are **overlapped**, which was a large visibility problem of old pager.

Additionally, one can use `pagerCenterWidth`, `pagerLeftWidth` or `pagerRightWidth` options to change the default width of tree parts of the pager. You can set one or two of the parameters to improve the visibility of the pager.

Comment: Got it!  That cleared everything up.  Thanks for your help!